# filter section is not working proper in elastalert, I am getting alerts on each minute

Tags: devops, elastalert

I am trying to set alert configuration using elastalert.
IN the file example_frequency.yaml I am stuck in filter section, where if I try this

```
filter:
- match:
       message: "Could not connect to mongoDB"
```

In that case It alerts me  on matching every single  word So I am  getting alerts which I don't want.
I also tried query-filter but didn't get the solution.
Is there any misconfiguration I am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using *keyword* fields instead to filter out exact matches

```
filter:
- match:
       message.keyword: "Could not connect to mongoDB"
```

Alternate Filter:

```
- query:
    query_string:
      query: 'message.keyword: "Could not connect to mongoDB"'
```